# css) margin doesn't work

Tags: html, css

Whole code : http://jsfiddle.net/o3omng/Vh3u9/

```
<div id="as_profile" class="div_clearboth"></div>
<div id="as_notice" class="div_clearboth"></div>
```

In the HTML code, `#as_profile` and `#as_notice` are 
both have `class="div_clearboth"` attribute.

```
.div_clearboth { clear : both ;
                 margin-bottom : 10px ; }
```

In the CSS code, 
I give clear:both style and `margin-bottom : 10px style` to `div_clearboth` attribute.

It works well in other div tags,
but It doesn't work well in `#as_profile`.

Check the jsfiddle. Then you can see that there is no space between `#as_profile` and `#as_notice`.
They must be 10px away. How can I fix it?

Whole code : http://jsfiddle.net/o3omng/Vh3u9/

`<s_somethig>` tag and [##*something*##] are going to replace by server automatically.

Comment: Hm, are you sure? I looked at your JSFiddle and when I changed the margins to 50, 100, etc., I was definitely noticing the margin changing. 10px is relatively small.

Comment: I can see the 10px gap just fine.

Comment: @user3ffgfgfgfgfg50064 Then why the separation between #as_profile and #as_notice The separation between #as_profile and #as_category are different? I can't find the reason. My browser's problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can correct it by giving `#as_profile` an overflow value besides visible:

```
#profile_control {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Or changing display to inline block:

```
#profile_control {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Or giving it padding/border:

```
#profile_control {
    padding: 1px 0 0 0;
}
```

As @sevenseacat pointed out, the culprit is the floated `li`'s within `#as_profile`

Comment: there's nothing to 'fix'.

Comment: right, I had a closer look and now I can see that the `#profile_control` div is taking up no space due to the floated elements within. Seems fair.

Comment: @sevenseacat: Yes ... using the above rules on `#as_profile` would probably make more sense on `#profile_control` now that you point that out.

Comment: You mean li tags are floated so #as_notice was placed 10px under the #profile_profile. I got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

CSS :

```
#as_profile {
    padding-bottom:20px;
}
```

Can you use Padding for divide? It works for me.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o3omng/Vh3u9/)